# React TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a function to calculate the individual column total of 12 rows and create a new array of the total values of the same size but i keep getting the error

**TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**
how do i resove it

new_matrix of dimension [6][12] is pre calculated and then passed into the colTotaler function as
also the matrix input is obtained through a matrix input form

colToataler(new_matrix);

```
let columns = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

const[col,setCol] = useState(columns);

const colTotaler = (new_matrix) => {
   let i = 0,
     j = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < new_matrix[0].length; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < new_matrix.length; j++) {
       columns[i] += new_matrix[i][j];
     }
   }

   setCol(columns);
 };
```

Comment: `comumns` on line `1` isn't the same as `columns` on line `3`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to define `new_matrix`

Comment: How do you call `colTotaler` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you choose to calculate colTotaler isn't good enought. I would suggest you to do this in functional way, using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and reactivity of React:

```
const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState(defaultMatrix)

const colTotaler = matrix.map((column) => {
  return column.reduce((colTotal, element) => colTotal+ element, 0)
})
```

Now, every time when `setMatrix` will be called, component will rerendered and colTotaler will be recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `new_matrix` from state, the initial value of the state could be undefined. To fix that you can add if statement to check it state is initialized:

```
let comumns = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

const[col,setCol] = useState(columns);

const colTotaler = (new_matrix) => {
   if (new_matrix) {
     let i = 0,
       j = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < new_matrix[0].length; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < new_matrix.length; j++) {
         columns[i] += new_matrix[i][j];
       }
     }

     setCol(columns);
   }
 };
```